# Cut last two lines of a file and append to another file repeatedly

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, tail

I tried the following command to cut out the last two lines of a file and append them to a new file

```
tail -n -2 file1 >> file2 && head -n -2 file1 > tmp && mv tmp file1
```

With the above code on every manual execution, the last two lines of **file1** get cut out and append to **file2**. But what would be the best way to do that automatically until **file1** has no more entries to cut out?

Or even do you have a method to do this in a completely different way?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework assignment, not a real life problem.

Comment: @HuHa believe me its a real life problem :)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it would be simpler to read pairs of lines in reverse order using `tac`

```
tac file1 | while IFS= read -r a && IFS= read -r b; do printf '%s\n%s\n' "$b" "$a"; done >> file2
```

(this will terminate when there are fewer than 2 lines left in `file1` - thanks [u/artur meinild](https://askubuntu.com/users/1066942/artur-meinild)) or

```
tac file1 | sed -E '$!N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\n\1/' >> file2
```

(which will continue to the end of `file1` even if it has an odd number of lines<sup>1</sup>).

Or a similar method using GNU `parallel`:

```
tac file1 | parallel -N2 "printf '%s\n'" '{2}' '{1}' >> file2
```

---

1. if you want to use sed, but ignore a trailing odd line as the while-loop version does, change to `sed -nE '$!N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\n\1/p'` which only prints on successful substitution

Comment: Your first option does not work if `file1` has an odd number of lines - then the first line isn't transferred to `file2` as the last line. However, the question didn't mention if this should be the case, but I thought it should. I didn't test with `parallel`. I still upvoted though. 

Comment: @ArturMeinild good point - let's see if the OP clarifies their question

Answer (score 0):

This is the beginner friendly version, using a script with a while loop that is easy to read and understand:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do this operation as long as file1 has content
while [[ -n $(cat file1) ]]
do
  # Put the 2 last lines of file1 in file2
  tail -n -2 file1 >> file2
  # Remove the last 2 lines of file1
  head -n -2 file1 > tmp && mv -f tmp file1
done

# If you want to remove the empty file1
# rm -f file1
```

This solution works even if `file1` has an odd number of lines (then the first line of `file1` will be the last line of `file2`).

Answer (score 0):

OK guys thx for your suggestions.
I tried all the day and struggled with some code but finally I have my solution working. What are your thoughts about...
I do a until loop similar to what Arthur Meinild mentioned.

```
until ! [ -s file_tmp ]; do
tail -n -2 file_tmp >> file.tmp && seq 2 | xargs -i sed -i -e '$d' file_tmp
done
rm file_tmp && cat file.tmp >> file
rm file.tmp
```

I had other solutions with head instead of sed but head turns out way more heavy disk io.
The steeldriver version from above seems also interesting to me but for now I will go the sed way :)

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`, you can e.g save the file lines to an array then set a counter(*to be used to call the indexes of the array in reverse*) that you decrement by two after each `print` action while printing tow lines at a time in their original order within an `if ... else ..` to handle files with both odd or even line numbers like so:

```bash
awk '{ a[i++]=$0 } END {
       for (l=i-1; l>=0; l=l-2) {
       if (l > 0) {
       print a[l-1]"\n"a[l] 
       } else {
       print a[l]
    }}}' file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with three commands.

(seq 10 provides a sample input file)

```
seq 10 | sed  -n '1~2p' | tac > odds
seq 10 | sed  -n '2~2p' | tac > evens
awk  '{getline line < "evens"; print $0; print line}'  odds

9
10
7
8
5
6
3
4
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a single awk command:

```
tac input_file | awk 'NR%2==0{print $0"\n"second};NR%2==1{second=$0}'
```